# Why does this Query return "OK"? about "delete"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause, sql-delete

```
+------------+--------+----------+-------+-----+--------+
| customerid | id     | password | level | age | name   |
+------------+--------+----------+-------+-----+--------+
|          1 | L1234  | 12345A   | J1    |  24 |        |
|          2 | L12134 | 12345a   | J1    |  23 | SYPARK |
+------------+--------+----------+-------+-----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELETE FROM customer WHERE age='23';
```

1.  Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> DELETE FROM customer WHERE age='23';
```

2.  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

at this situation. why does this Query return "OK"? which is number 2.

I thought it would not work(get the Error). because the data isn't exist that was removed before Query number of 2.

but I got the result of OK. Why is this like this?

Comment: You asked it to delete all matching records. It deleted none, because there are none. That's OK. If you want to check whether things exist and fail otherwise, check/report that yourself. "Why is it like this?" Check the ANSI SQL standard, I guess. There's no error inherent in having no matching records.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force mysql to throw error if no rows deleted (trying to delete non-existent row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774569/force-mysql-to-throw-error-if-no-rows-deleted-trying-to-delete-non-existent-row)

Answer (score 2):

> at this situation. why does this Query return "OK"?

`Query OK` just means that the query executed without errors (either syntax errors or runtime errors) - which is the case here: the query did not fail, it just did not find any record to `delete`.

You can see in the remaining of the message, however, that the query did not *affect* any row; this being a `DELETE` statement, it means that no rows was deleted.

Comment: THANK YOU ! I'm very HAPPY. NOW I CAN UNDERSTAND!